# layout, valign-center, and position: absolute not working correctly in Materialize.css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am relatively new to Front-end development and am trying to make a webpage. I am using Materialize.css as my framework. Problems I am facing:

1. I have placed four custom logos on top of each other to crossfade them. However, the menu that is supposed to appear below them is placed from the beginning of the webpage. I can use margin-top on the menu, but, I want to know an alternate solution that automatically places the menu `(id="menu1")` just after the images. Please see the images to see what I'm trying to achieve.

Current layout:
[image: Current layout of webpage]
What I am trying to achieve:
[image: What I am trying to achieve]

2. Also, is there a wrapper class for side-navigation bar in materialize.css
   The one I'm using is without any wrapper class (`id="menu1"`) and the second one is hidden and has to be shown using jquery (`id="mobnav"`). I want a side navigation bar that is always shown. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
3. The font icons and the text are not vertically aligned. Meaning the home icon and the text "Home" are at different heights. Same goes for all the menu items. How best to address this?
4. Lastly, I want to center my menu (`id="menu1"`) to the center of the `class="col s4 m4 l2"`. For this, I change the height of the div to 100vh and use the class `"valign-center"` on the menu (`id="menu1"`). But, it is not working. Why won't it work?

Am I missing anything?

Jquery code (js.script):

```js
$(window).on("load", function(e) {
  $(".pre-loader").fadeOut("slow");
});

$(function() {

  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

});
```

CSS code(style.css):

```
.logo img {
  position: absolute;
}

.nav1 li {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.flarge {
  font-size: 36px !important;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>      
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Test</title> 
    </head> 

    <body>  

        <div class="pre-loader"></div>

        <section id="home" class="page-section">            

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col s4 m4 l2" style="background-color: teal;">

                    <div style="position: relative;" class="logo">
                        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://ibb.co/jVy6Yw" alt="Logo">
                        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://ibb.co/jVy6Yw" alt="Logo">
                        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://ibb.co/jVy6Yw" alt="Logo">
                        <img class="responsive-img" src="https://ibb.co/jVy6Yw" alt="Logo">
                    </div>

                    <div id="menu1" class="hide-on-med-and-down">

                        <ul class="nav1">
                            <a href="#home"><li><i class="material-icons flarge valign" aria-hidden="true">home</i> &nbsp; Home</li></a>
                            <a href="#about"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">help</i> &nbsp; About</li></a>
                            <a href="#events"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">event</i> &nbsp; Events</li></a>
                            <a href="#ourteam"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">people</i> &nbsp; Our Team</li></a>
                            <a href="#contacts"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">account_box</i> &nbsp; Contacts</li></a>    
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <nav style="background-color: transparent; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        <a href="#" data-activates="mobnav" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons flarge">menu</i></a>
                        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobnav">
                            <a href="#home"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">home</i> &nbsp; Home</li></a>
                            <a href="#about"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">help</i> &nbsp; About</li></a>
                            <a href="#events"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">event</i> &nbsp; Events</li></a>
                            <a href="#ourteam"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">people</i> &nbsp; Our Team</li></a>
                            <a href="#contacts"><li><i class="material-icons flarge" aria-hidden="true">account_box</i> &nbsp; Contacts</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                </div>

            </div>


        </section>                                                                              <!--end of home -->



        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    </body> 
</html>



<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a class divider underneath it asw shown on the website of materialize.css , i think it might be able to create a large enough spacer underneath the "logo" for your goal that your trying to achieve here. :)